# Can I Customize LinqPad shortcut keys?

Tags: keyboard, intellisense, shortcut, hotkeys, linqpad

I am accustomed to using <kbd>ESC</kbd> to "list members" and <kbd>F1</kbd> to "show parameter info" in Visual Studio.  This is an old habit from XCode.  Is there any way to achieve this in LinqPad?  I noticed an advanced preference called "use visual studio shortcut keys". My first thought is that this option would copy your key mapping settings from visual studio into LinqPad, but that does not seem to be how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to customize keyboard shortcuts in LINQPad right now. The "Use Visual Studio shortcut keys" option (for which the default is TRUE) just tells LINQPad to use shortcuts consistent with VS's defaults.

Setting this option to false makes it consistent with early versions of LINQPad which used single-key combinations for things like comment/uncomment rather than the VS-style chords.

Comment: That is unfortunate, but I bought it anyway. LinqPad is fantastic. I use it every day.

Comment: Are there any plans to add custom keybinding in the future? This was answered in 2011 so I thought I'd see. The Visual Studio shortcuts are fine for the most part, however I have some AutoHotKey scripts that override most of my F-keys. It would be nice if I could bind the F-key shortcuts in LinqPad to something else. It would be a nice luxury to have. I have separate monitor just for LinqPad, so it goes without saying that I love your work. Thanks